# PHP: How to post to more then one page with if statements

Tags: php

Ok, here's my ordeal; I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction here. I've got a form which is a multi-page php wizard but each subsequent page is dependent upon the chosen option in a select box. I have it redirecting to the appropriate page when clicking submit based on the selection but the information is not being posted to the page. So my question is how can I post to both pages so that which ever one is loaded next can have the information entered in the previous. Here is an example of my current code.

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>


<?php

//let's start the session
session_start();

//now, let's register our session variables
session_register('info from last page');

//finally, let's store our posted values in the session variables
$_SESSION['info from last page'] = $_POST['info from last page'];
echo $_SESSION["info from last page"];


//redirect to appropriate page based on selected option
    function redirect($where){       
       header("Location: $where"); 
    } 
    if ($_REQUEST['audio'] == 'option1'){ 
        redirect('http://www.avwebcasting.com/ordering_system/webcast/step3ressless.php'); 
    }elseif($_REQUEST['audio'] == 'option2'){ 
        redirect('http://www.avwebcasting.com/ordering_system/webcast/step3oa.php'); 
    } 

?>


<form method="post" id="step2" name="step2" action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>">

<label>
<span>*Audio:</span>
<select name="audio" class="select">
<option value="option1" selected="selected">option1</option>
<option value="option2">option2</option>
</select>
</label>
                  <INPUT TYPE="submit" name="submit"/>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just an unrelated critique, try to take it as the constructive criticism it is. `Lets start the session` is a bad comment. It's longer than the code it's documenting, which is clear enough already - nobody needs a comment to know that `session_start` starts a session. You should be documenting the logic behind your code, not the code itself. Same with `session_register`. Your comments should indicate *why* you're registering variables, not that you *are* registering variables; anybody can see that that's what you're doing, but you can't immediately tell why you're doing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I answered my own question after hours of research. Turns out it works flawlessly with some javascript; so I'm posting the answer to my own question to help anyone else who might come to these crossroads.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function PostMultiple()
{
if(document.step2.audio[0].selected == true) {
   document.step2.action = 'http://gohere.html';
   }
if(document.step2.audio[1].selected == true) {
   document.step2.action = 'http://gothere.html';
   document.myform.method = 'get';
   }
return true;
}
 </script>
```

Answer (score 3):

for starters the reason your session is not working is because your outputting data before session starts

```
<html>          <<<
<head></head>   <<<
<body>          <<<
<?php
//let's start the session
session_start(); //this fails
```

This should be like so

```
<?php
//let's start the session
session_start(); //now it works :D
?>

<html>
<head></head>
<body>
```

Comment: please also turn error reporting on whiles in dev mode, add `error_reporting(E_ALL)` before `session_start()` to see whats up with PHP

Answer (score 0):

You can in option value get name of php file to reditect, then you can use one line solution:

```
redirect('http://www.avwebcasting.com/ordering_system/webcast/' . stripslashes($_REQUEST['audio']) . '.php');
```

or I miss understand the question

Answer (score 0):

This.

```
<?
session_start();
?>

<html>
<head></head>
<body>

<?
$locationArray = array(
'option1' => '/ordering_system/webcast/step3ressless.php',
'option2' => '/ordering_system/webcast/step3oa.php'
);

if(isset($_REQUEST['audio'])){
    if(array_key_exists($_REQUEST['audio'],$locationArray)){
        $location = $locationArray[$_REQUEST['audio']];
        header('Location: '.$location);
        exit;
    }
}

// No one submitted the audio variable.. fall through to the form

?>


<form method="post" id="step2" name="step2" action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>">

<label>
<span>*Audio:</span>
<select name="audio" class="select">
<option value="option1" selected="selected">option1</option>
<option value="option2">option2</option>
</select>
</label>
                  <INPUT TYPE="submit" name="submit"/>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `if(array_key_exists($_REQUEST['audio']))` ... please revise.

Comment: tried Ollie's example, but information is still not being carried over.  Thanks to all for their responses